# Basic Piecewise Function: Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

> I am trying to prove why $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at all points besides $5$, but I am having trouble starting this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 -1& \text{if $x<5$} \\ 
  0& \text{if $x=5$} \\ 
  1& \text{if $x>5$.} \\
\end{matrix}\right.$

I have tried to work backwards by trying to find a value for $\delta$ as I am wanting to show the following when $b\neq 5$:

|$f(x)-f(b)|<\epsilon$ when $f(x)$ is given just like above and $f(b)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 -1& \text{if $b<5$} \\ 
  0& \text{if $b=5$} \\ 
  1& \text{if $b>5$.} \\
\end{matrix}\right.$

My mind just sees too many cases going on to try to solve the problem this way.

Comment: It could be helpful to actually make a graph of this function. It is not a proof, but it may facilitate it

Comment: I see that it is continuous at all points besides $5$, but I still do not see how to start proving it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $x > 5$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Pick $\delta = x-5$ and note that for all $y$ satisfying $|x-y| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| = |1-1| = 0 < \epsilon$. This proves that the function is continuous on $(5,\infty)$.

**Follow up**: Note that the particular value of $\epsilon > 0$ does not influence our choice of $\delta$. Why do you think this is the case?

**Your turn**: Can you repeat the argument for the interval $(-\infty, 5)$?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but why do you let $x>5$? I must be missing something there. I thought for this function to be continuous $x\in \mathbb{R}$, so that $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$: $\exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$: $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$: $|x-b|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(b)|<\epsilon$ when $b\neq 5$.

Comment: What allows you to break up the $x's$ like that?

Comment: I am checking to see if the function is continuous at some point $x > 5$. Note that since $x > 5$, there is always a positive distance between $x$ and $5$ (i.e., this distance is $\delta = x - 5$). For example, I could be checking continuity at the point $x=6$, or $x=5.5$, or even $x=5.000001$. This is what allows me to **break it up into two cases**, namely $x>5$ and $x<5$.